# BlueJ Array List parameters. 

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I have created a class with Array Lists  in Blue J for my assignment and it compiles but I don't know how to test it. 
What do I have to type(parameter?) in method call for a method such as

```
public void addJob(Job job) 

public boolean runJob()
```

I understand that for int I just have to type numbers such as 2, and String "B".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have to create an instance of your `Job` class and give it a name, e.g. `job1`. This can be done by right-clicking on the class and then clicking on `new Job()`. The resulting object will be listed in the box at the bottom of the BlueJ window and can be used in your BlueJ project.

Now call the method `addJob(Job job)` with `job1` (just type in the name of the object, without quotes) as the parameter and your test should work.